# css/js rollover breaking with multiple rollovers

Tags: javascript, css

Client asked for two rollovers to pop down from their social media icons at the top of the page

This is the page on dev:
http://devjohnson.com/the-buzz
Ignore missing images and design - it has the same images and header files as live - its just fully updated.

If you look at the top right corner, you can see if you rollover facebook icon (besides the positioning) it works as we want.  However, if I un-comment the exact same code for the Twitter icon, it breaks and the Facebook icon disappears and the Twitter one doesnt roll over.  We need both to rollover and be positioned correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Caroline

Comment: dublin! this codepen is better actually http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvLwdx its about half 4 in the day here

Comment: i asked a q on SO to solve the last piece of the puzzle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749114/how-do-i-get-elements-to-disable-when-i-click-on-another-element/31749399?noredirect=1#comment51432981_31749399 how about voting it up??? ;)

Comment: the 1134 is how i want it - but i cant move my mouse down to click the links in the rollover - the other ones arent right...

Comment: I copied it to the dev site
http://devjohnson.com/the-buzz
The rollovers work in the fiddle but not in the dev site

Comment: ahem http://rachelgallen.com/testingso1.html and i see you have 15 rep now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start for you!

```js
$('#clickable_div').mouseover(function() {
  $('#nav_menu').slideDown();
})
$('#wrap').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#nav_menu').slideUp();
});
```

```css
#clickable_div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#nav_menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background-color:#fff; 
  border:1px solid red;
  display: none;
}
#wrap {
  width: 100px
}
.fb {
  background-image: url("http://devjohnson.com/skin/frontend/dJTheme/default/images/facebook_icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id="clickable_div" class="fb">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="l1">AAAAA</li>
      <li>BBBBB</li>
      <li>CCCCC</li>
      <li>DDDDD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```