# How do i get elements to disable when i click on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have 5 social media buttons in a row, 2 of which have menus which are triggered by jquery slidetoggle. The problem is, that when the twitter button is clicked it rearranges the icons as the menu appears and knocks them all out of place. How do i prevent this?

Here is my code:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {


  $(this).closest('.comment').find(".box").toggle();



});
```

```css
#icons {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0px!important;
}
.comment {
  width: 140px;
  float: right;
}
.button {
  width: 25px;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top!important;
  height: 25px;
}
.box {
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 25px;
}
.box ul {
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
ul.tw {
  border: 0px;
}
li.normal {
  margin-right: 25px!important;
  width: 80px;
}
li.tw {
  margin-right: 60px;
  width: 80px;
}
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
li {
  padding: 0!important;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}
a {
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="icons">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="button">
      <img src="http://devjohnson.com/skin/frontend/dJTheme/default/images/facebook_icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="hidden">
      <ul class="normal">
        <li class="normal"><a href="https://twitter.com/theoriginaldoc" target="_blank">DocJohnson</a>

        </li>
        <li class="normal"><a href="https://twitter.com/askthedocshow">Ask The Doc</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="button">
      <img src="http://devjohnson.com/skin/frontend/dJTheme/default/images/twitter_icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="hidden">
      <ul class="tw">
        <li class="tw"><a href="https://twitter.com/theoriginaldoc" target="_blank">DocJohnson</a>

        </li>
        <li class="tw"><a href="https://twitter.com/askthedocshow">Ask The Doc</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <a href="http://docjohnsonusa.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://devjohnson.com/skin/frontend/dJTheme/default/images/tumblr_icon.png" id="socialImage" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/DOCJOHNSON1976" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://devjohnson.com/skin/frontend/dJTheme/default/images/youtube_icon.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="http://instagram.com/docjohnsonusa" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://devjohnson.com/skin/frontend/dJTheme/default/images/instagram_icon.png" />
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  </body>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sCg/15/)

Comment: try putting those menu with position absolute, it should solve your problem

Comment: have you tried position absolute?

Comment: Must be related to a `relative` position of the `.box`. Don't forget that the *id* must be **unique**. You should add `hidden` as a *class* instead of an *id*: `class="box hidden"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it can break your layout, but it worked adding `position:absolute` to the `#hidden` element:

```
#hidden {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sCg/16/)**</kbd>. Also added `margin-top: -10px` because the `.box` value of `-20px` was making the div get over the button.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of CSS things to fix. But the main thing is a combination of position `relative` and `absolute` to make the dropdowns position properly.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvLwdx

```
   #icons {
text-align: center;
}
.comment {
  display: inline-block;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
}
.box ul {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
a {
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the codepen now and cleaned up the unnecessary code and other issues.

Comment: your codepen is really great but it would be a bit un-sporting of me to unaccept the other answer. I'll vote you up on another of your answers

Answer (score 1):

I have copied all of your code to a jsFiddle, all you need to do is add `position: absolute` to your `.box` class like so

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/g1Lfg7y5/

CSS

```
#icons {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 0px!important;
}
.comment {
    width: 140px;
    float: right;
}
.button {
    width: 25px;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: top!important;
    height: 25px;
}
.box {
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
.box ul {
    width: 80px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
ul.tw {
    border: 0px;
}
li.normal {
    margin-right: 25px!important;
    width: 80px;
}
li.tw {
    margin-right: 60px;
    width: 80px;
}
#hidden {
    display: none;
}
li {
    padding: 0!important;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
}
a {
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of inconsistencies here.

First of all turn hidden into a class. It repeats itself more than once so it can't be an id.

Then try:

```
.hidden
{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

I tested it and it worked.

Comment: the lists show up by default if i use your solution

Comment: that's not the answer you gave, that's with hidden as an id still